# How to set up Named Credentials for NiCE inContact Central API?

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out how to set up a Named Credential for the inContact API. I've been searching for specific documentation or examples, but no luck yet.

I've currently got the authentication working in my test code, with hardwired credentials working directly with the NICE authentication API. Obviously that won't do going forward. I'm not sure how the two-stage process maps to Named Credentials.

This is the documentation I referred to when building my hardwired version (that works as expected):
https://developer.niceincontact.com/Documentation/GettingStarted

First, I am doing a POST to https://api.incontact.com/InContactAuthorizationServer/Token with Basic Authorization. That returns an access token, base url (which is different than the previous URL - something like "https://api-XXX.incontact.com/..."), refresh token, and refresh url that I use in subsequent calls to other api endpoints.

Then, any other API calls use "Bearer " + access_token.

(And of course, I refresh the token as needed.)

Here's my current Named Credential attempt:

[image: Picture of Named Credential]

When I attempt test by doing a basic GET call, I get an HTTP Response of [Status=Found, StatusCode=302].

I don't know if the URL I am using is correct or if I need to be using the full InContactAuthorizationServer/Token url that I show above.

Also, for username, I am not sure if I should be using AppName@VendorName:BusinessUnitNumber or the base-64 encoded version. I've tried both.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting this set up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please edit your question and show your work.

Comment: Thanks @identigral - I've added some more detail here.

Comment: You need the full URL in there, including `InContactAuthorizationServer/Token`. NC base64-encodes username/password for you.

Comment: Well, getting a 404 now - not sure if that's progress or not. I tried to use Fiddler to see what's actually being sent over the wire, but that doesn't seem to work. Anyway, I'll keep digging.